# How to name something that is common for two competing theories?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Geocentric and early heliocentric models of cosmos were different at the very core of theory, but they did share some elements: circular orbits, epicycles, uniform speed of celestial bodies.

**What words/phrases can be used to refer to these things that they had in common?**

In my native language I could say "obszar wspólny", which could be literally translated to "common area", "shared field" or similar. But scientific theories obviously does not have any "area" that you can measure and I am unsure whether metaphorical meaning of word functions in English.

Is "commonalities" ("commonalities of geocentric and heliocentric models") good enough?

Comment: "Shared assumptions", "Common Principles", "Common Foundation" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Common ground** is the [English equivalent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/common_ground) of the idiom you mention.

Answer (score 0):

commonality/ies

- A shared feature or atribute. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonality)
- A shared feature or quality [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonality)

Geocentric and early heliocentric models of cosmos were different at the very core of theory, **but showed certain commonalities.**

You could also use one of these:

> - Geocentric and early heliocentric models of cosmos **have the following similarities...**
> - Geocentric and early heliocentric models of cosmos **have the following characteristics in common**...
> - Geocentric and early heliocentric models of cosmos **share a few characteristics** but are, in fact, two distinct...

similarity - point, feature, or detail in which two items are alike. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/similarities)

characteristic - a special quality or trait that makes a person, thing, or group different from others. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/characteristic)

Answer (score 0):

*Commonalities* could work. It isn't bad. There's *overlap* too, but that's still not perfect.

You could rephrase to something like *the theories shared ideas*. It's a good question.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in previous answers, *[commonalities](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commonalities?rdfrom=Commonalities)* is a word you could use; from [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commonality#Noun), *commonality* has a sense “shared attribute or characteristic”.  But I'd prefer wording that refers to *common elements* or *shared aspects*.  For example:
•  The theories have these **elements in common**: ...
•  **Aspects shared** by the two theories include ...